# (menu)Items not clickable on IPhone using Bootstrap

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using latest Bootstrap version.
A website-user, using an Iphone, **can't click** on menu-items (navbar etc).

Should this work well nowadays (february-26-2015) with latest Bootstrap on any IPhone / Pad / Pod.

New-info-1: other IPhone-user say: ThisLinkWorksWell-1 and ThisLinkWorksWell-2 works well, but collapse menu is not working.

New-info-2: it seems 2 links are not working: 1) share-button-FaceBook 2) collapse-menu-BT .... both javascript !?

ALL used files I droped in: www.WeTransfer.com (download til 6 March) downloadlink=http://we.tl/8dvkmYCSLa

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="nl">

            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

            <!-- CSS files -->
            <link href="bt/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="bt/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <title>Home</title>

            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div><!--/navbar-header-->
                            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav LijnNav">
                                    <a class="btn" href="index.html" title="Home" role="Home">Home</a>        
                                    <a class="btn" href="page-n.html" title="page-n" role="page-n">page-n</a>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                        </nav>


                            <a href="http://ThisLinkWorksWell.nl" TARGET="_blank"><img src="ThisLinkWorksWell.png" alt="ThisLinkWorksWell-1" title="ThisLinkWorksWell-1">
                            </a>


                        <br><input class="btn btnV btn-default" type="button" value="TopPage-WorksWell-2" onclick="location.href = '#Top'" />
                    </div><!--/col -->
                </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->

                <script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script async src="bt/js/jqueryGoogle.min.js"></script>
                <script async src="bt/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>



CSS -------------------
            @charset "utf-8";
            /* CSS Document */
            .container {
                background: rgba(255,255,220,1);
                border-radius: 6px;
            }
            .btnV {/*vorm*/
                border-top-color: #eeeeee;
                border-top-width: 2px;
                border-top-style: solid;
                height: 45px;
                margin: 6px 0px 16px 8px;
                padding-top: 8px;
                position: relative;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 90px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 90px;
                border-top-left-radius: 90px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 90px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 90px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 90px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 90px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
            }
            .btn:hover {
                border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
            }
            li, p {
                line-height: 1.28em;
            }
            .LijnNav {
                margin: 5px -15px 0px -15px;/*T,R,B,L*/
                border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            }

            @media (min-width:768px) {
            .LijnNav {
                margin: -8px 0px 0px 0px;/*T,R,B,L*/
            }
```

Comment: OK, it should work ... Any suggestion what adjustment on the IPhone blocked the "Bootstrap-clicks"  ... or is it maybe an older IPhone-type (or IOS-version) that is not working well with BT?

Comment: It's impossible to say since you didn't post any of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested several IPhones in phone-store. All are working well. So: problem is not BT, but related to IPhone.
Maybe not latest updates installed or very old IPhone (...they say in store) ?!

Comment: It is indeed specific (old) Iphone(s).